# Converting a List of Lists to HashTable in Java

Tags: java, graph, hashmap

I have a list of lists containing source and destination. For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>();}
```

["A","B"]

["A","C"]

["A","D"]

["B","E"]

I would like to convert this into hashmap like

`HashMap<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();`

A : B,C,D

B : E

How do I go about doing this ?

Function which I have

```
static class Edge {
     public String source;
     public String destination;

     public Edge(String source, String destination) {
       this.source = source;
       this.destination = destination;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Hint: you can do something like `HashMap<String, List<Edge>>` and check the `keyset` for any duplicates

Comment: @NicholasK I have updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over each edge and add it to your map :

```
for (Edge edge : edges) {
    if (!map.containsKey(edge.source)) 
        map.put(edge.source, new ArrayList<String>());
    map.get(edge.source).add(edge.destination);
}
```

Comment: Use this solution if for some reason you can't use Java8+ else Nicholas K solution is cooler ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do :

```
Map<String, List<String>> collMap = edges.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Edge::getSource, 
                     Collectors.mapping(Edge::getDestination, Collectors.toList())));
```

which gives the output :

> {A=[B, C, D], B=[E]}